# issue after merging with wrong branch

Tags: git, merge, pom.xml, git-merge

My local branch is gen-1000. I first merged Release_1 into gen-1000. There is some conflict in the pom.xml. I chose to use theirs(Release_1). After that, I modified pom.xml. I wanted to merge Release_1 into gen-1000 again and use my pom to mark it resolved. But I accidently merge **Develop** into my gen-1000. But I am stuck. I can't choose to merge Release_1 into my branch anymore. And I can't checkin. It keeps giving me below error.

```
remote: No Jira issues found in the following commits:        
remote: 5bcb5f2f640 Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/Develop' into gen-1000        
remote: f8e6c48eef6 Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/Release_1' into gen-1000
  # Conflicts: #    pom.xml #   src/main/resources/Bl...        
remote: 
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://bitbucket/scm/gen/xxx.git'
To https://bitbucket/scm/gen/xxx.git
!   refs/heads/gen-1000:refs/heads/gen-1000 [remote rejected] (pre-receive hook declined)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, do not merge integration branches (release or develop) into topic branches (like `gen-1000`)

*Rebase* your topic branch on top of the target branch you want ultimately to merge to.

Second, try and reset your local branch to *before* the wrong merge (the one from `Develop`), and try again.